# View is not displaying after moving from viewWillLayoutSubviews to viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have been trying to teach myself Objective-C but I am having some trouble with views.

After moving everything from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLoad` my scene is not presenting itself.  The code in MyScene.m is working, I just cannot see it.  Is there some glaring flaw that I am missing here?

The previous `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is available below.  Everything here was cut straight into `viewDidLoad` excluding `[super viewDidLayoutSubviews]`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) 
    {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeRight)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedLeft)];
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeLeft)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
    swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeUp)];

}
```

If it helps, I moved everything from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLoad` to avoid re-creating the gesture recognizers every time the view rotates.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you do that? The accepted way to initialize a SKScene is in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Simply move creating the gesture recognizers inside the `!skView.scene` block:

```
if (!skView.scene) 
{
    // init everything here that should be initialized only once
    // AND should not re-run every time the view rotates
}
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Won't this create multiple swipe gesture recognizers?  If not, I may have gotten some bad advice.

Comment: No. Since once the SKView has a valid scene the scene property will never be nil again. Therefore this code runs once and only once.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you missed initialising your skView as follows

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
```

before accessing its scene property.

Comment: It looks like I deleted that line from my post while formatting.  Sorry about that.  It is in the application and I have added it back into the post.

Comment: when you say, you just cannot see it, what does it mean? Is your view display nothing?

Comment: I can see the number of nodes on screen and the FPS.  Now that I look at it though, it looks like the nodes are not being added.  I will need to play around with this more.

Comment: if you are rendering your scene on landscape mode then those landscape bound will not be taken into effect on viewDidLoad as the skView.bounds.size returns portrait bound, if you want landscape's bound then the you have to create and initialise skView on viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: edit: You completely answered my question.  I really appreciate the help.  I still do not know how to declare my gesture recognizers for use in MyScene if I create skView in viewWillLayoutSubviews but I suppose that is a separate question.

Comment: can you not add gesture on self.view in ViewDidLoad as skView is merely a pointer to self.view?

Comment: That errors out because the gesture recognizers are calling an action from MyScene.m, which the SKScene *scene is attached to.